# Improve TLB (translation lookaside buffer) hit rate to approach 100%?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, tlb

I'm reading how TLB works and I came across this:

[context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHrH0.jpg)

> Lots of workloads (though certainly not all) approach 100% TLB hit rate.

What kind of workloads? any example would really help.

Comment: Could you provide some more context, please? And where is that quote from? Approaching 100% and exactly 100% are two very different things. Also, your title does not fully reflect your actual question, so some clarification would be nice. A TLB will never have a hit rate of exactly 100%, so improving the hit rate to 100% is impossible without looking into the future, which is, as of now, infeasible.

Comment: @cad Thank you for the clarifications but I understand that. My question is: what workloads make it possible for TLB hit rate to **approach** 100% hit?

Comment: Then write that in your title. As I said, it does not fully reflect your actual question.

Comment: @cad okay I updated the title, thanks for pointing that out. there isn't much of a context since I saw it on an operating system class slides (not many details there just headlines).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good little paper I found through DuckDuckGo that explains quite well how the TLB works (part of a Comp Sci course from the University of Wisconsin-Madison, by the looks of it): [https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-tlbs.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/vm-tlbs.pdf). That should give you enough to start reasoning about how your data layout and algorithms might affect your TLB hit rate.

Essentially, it comes down to keeping things close together in memory, so you minimize the number of different pages you have to access when accessing your data and instructions. With 4K pages or larger being typical, it turns out that most programs typically will have a very high TLB hit rate. In fact, the computer systems we use today have been specifically *designed* this way, based on extensive research into what most computing workloads typically did before those systems were designed.

If you think about a function running without any branches, you can picture the sequential fetching and executing of each instruction, beginning at some point in a page and continuing down the page. The first instruction may result in a TLB miss, but every instruction after that will be a TLB hit, until the end of the page is reached. When the first instruction on the next page is accessed, there may be another TLB miss, but then the rest of the page of instructions will all be hits. It gets even better if the function contains a loop, because the CPU will jump back to something it just executed.  It may not even leave the same page for a long time.

Programs also tend to access data on pages that they have just recently accessed. For example, all the automatic variables within a function will typically reside on one or two stack pages, and in many cases, all the stack frames for all the functions in the call stack will often fit into a small number of pages. For heap-allocated or statically-allocated memory, there is usually some locality too. The paper I mention above gives a good example of how array traversals result in high TLB hit rates.

Workloads that tend to have relatively low TLB hit rates are those that spread their frequently-accessed data and/or instructions over a large number of pages, with infrequently-accessed data/instructions in between; and those that do things to invalidate their TLB entries (e.g., on some systems a process context switch results in the TLB being dumped).